# On measure-theoretic differentation under integral sign and correlation function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differentiation, path-integral, correlation-functions

Correlation function of $n$-many scalar fields is given by

$$\langle \Omega |T\{{\mathcal {\psi }}(x_{1})\dots {\mathcal {\psi}}(x_{n})\}|\Omega \rangle = \frac {\int_{\mathcal{F}}{\mathcal {D}}[\psi] \ \psi (x_{1})\dots \psi(x_{n})e^{iS[\psi]}}{\int_{\mathcal{F}}{\mathcal {D}}[\psi] \ e^{iS[\psi]}}\tag{1}$$

Where $|\Omega\rangle$denotes the vacuum state at every spacetime point. Under a field variation $\psi\rightarrow \hat{\psi} = \psi + \epsilon \delta\psi + O(\epsilon^2)$, where $\epsilon\in I\subset \mathbb{R}$ belongs to an open interval with $0\in I$,

$$\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\biggr|_{\epsilon = 0}\langle \Omega |T\{{\hat{\mathcal{\psi}}}(x_{1})\dots {\hat{\mathcal{\psi}}}(x_{n})\}|\Omega \rangle = \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\biggr|_{\epsilon = 0}\biggr({\frac {\int_{\mathcal{F}}{\mathcal{D}}[\hat{\psi}] \ \hat{\psi} (x_{1})\dots \hat{\psi}(x_{n})e^{iS[\hat{\psi}]}}{\int_{\mathcal{F}} {\mathcal{D}}[\hat{\psi}] \ e^{iS[\hat{\psi}]}}}\biggr)\tag{2}$$

Suppose that $(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{D})$ denotes the measure space of fields. A function $X : \mathcal{F}\times I\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ obeys Leibniz integral rule

$$\frac {d}{d\epsilon}\int_{\mathcal{F}} X(\psi,\epsilon)\,\mathcal{D}[\psi] = \int_{\mathcal{F}}\frac{\partial X}{\partial \epsilon}(\psi,\epsilon)\,\mathcal{D}[\psi]\tag{3}$$

Whenever

- $X(\cdot, \epsilon)\colon \mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is integrable for every $\epsilon\in I$,
- $\frac{\partial X}{\partial \epsilon}(\psi,\epsilon)$ exists for almost all $(\psi,\epsilon)\in \mathcal{F}\times I$,
- There exists $Y\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathcal{F})$ such that for every $\epsilon\in I$, $\left\lvert\frac{\partial X}{\partial \epsilon}(\psi,\epsilon)\right\rvert \leq Y(\psi)$.

Further suppose that $$X(\hat{\psi}, \epsilon) = \hat{\psi}(x_{1})\dots\hat{\psi}(x_{n})e^{iS[\hat{\psi]}}\tag{4}$$

With the help of $(3)$, can the derivative operator be moved inside the path integral in $(2)$?

---

Whatever is done above, demands that $\mathcal{D}$ is a Lebesgue measure, but infinite-dimensional $C^{\infty}(M)$ cannot be given one. Wilsonian perspective, on the other hand, suggests that we take a perturbative approach, i.e approximate by finite-dimensional $C^{\infty}_{\leq\Lambda}(M)$ that cuts off higher energy levels.

---

Comment: Is your question about how to rigorously move derivatives into the path integral? For real-time Feynman integrals, there is no such thing, I believe. The measure space $(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{D})$ you suppose does not exist (there is no Lebesgue measure on the space of field configurations). In Euclidean signature, one can make sense of the path integral measure for certain special classes of Hamiltonians, such as Gaussian theories, though.

Comment: At the rigor level of a physicist, We can move them around just like normal integrals. Why we can do so is not known.